# report from Qlik viever call SQL to postgres AWS using ODBC is slow and long

Tags: postgresql, qlikview

HiI have a problem with a query from QLIK Viever to AWS postgres databse. Recently the latter has been updated to the latest version and an ODBC is used on the Qlik server (on-prem) side.

The query, but let's call it procedure, is very long. Beyond the number of millions of records in some tables, the strange thing is that using the DBeaver JDBC provider client from the same Qlik machine this is executed after 20'. Via Qlik + ODBC fails to finish it and just stays, unless I reduce the time range of dates.

From this I deduce:

- ODBC provider is less performant than JDBC (I know this naturally)
- Could the postgres update might have brought some changes to the plans?

I'm revising the query... since I have no vision of the past... but they keep asking me why it works with one provider and not with another.

How could I proceed other than updating the latest ODBC driver on the networking side?

Thanks, ALEN

Comment: Without seeing your statemens or procedures I can't answer but I can suggest you some best pratice. Optimize your procedure, if it is a query try to reduce the columns to the essentials you are using in your qlik model, and make tuning to optimize your data access, i.e. using indexes. In adding, Qlikview does not officially support jdbc but some 3rd parties does. try different connectors, and if you have qliksense use its built-in performance analyzer or third-party monitoring tools to track the performance of your query and identify any potential issues.

Comment: Thanks Andrea for your reply...
yes I'm working on query tunning... I think also this is the primary problem... 'cause there are millions of record and not always the right approach to the statement of the query, by the way, the thing that most intrigues me is to understand the reason why via ODBC it doesn't solve and using  DBbeaver (JDBC) it solves. 

This is the thing they ask me... I analyzed the ODBC settings... I increased some parameter but for beyond this I cannot do more. I remain convinced that there is a wrong approach to data... and I am taking action to resolve this.
THANK YOU